# Haproxy1.5 graceful restart break the connection

Tags: haproxy, keep-alive

I have a problem about graceful restart in Haproxy1.5: when I use default configuration( don't add option http-tunnel), the client connects to the Haproxy server with POST method, then restart haproxy with the command "haproxy -D -f haproxy.conf -sf haproxy.pid", the client found the connection brokens; *But* if I add option http-tunnel(the default mode in Haproxy1.4)in default section,restart it gracefully with the above command, and the connection does not broken. 
   I want to know why the default option http-keep-alive can't restart gracefully or how the option-tunnel affect the connection? Is this a bug or just implemented in Haproxy1.5? Anyone can give me some hints?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Option `http-tunnel` was used by default in `versions 1.0 to 1.5-dev21`.

Is your client sending multiple HTTP requests in a TCP connection? It will broken when sending next HTTP request (while Haproxy is restarting). Haproxy does not support back-end server keep-alive. See details search `http-tunnel` in this document: http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt